# How to add new row to table as per the given structure

Tags: jquery

I need to construct the following HTML dynamically

```
<tr>
     <td><label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkclass">A<span></span></label></td>
     <td><label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkclass">B<span></span></label></td>
     <td><label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkclass">C<span></span></label></td>
     <td><label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkclass">D<span></span></label></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td><label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkclass" >E<span></span></label></td>
     <td><label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkclass">F<span></span></label></td>
     <td><label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkclass" >G<span></span></label></td>
     <td><label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkclass">H<span></span></label></td>
  </tr>
```

As you can see each **tr** should contain only **4 columns**

This is my code

While Initially showing the data i am using this piece of code and this is working fine

```
<table class="table" id="tagstable">
   <tbody>

   </tbody>
</table>

var myarray = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"]
$(document).ready(function()
{
        var html = ''
        for (var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++)
        {
                html += '<td><label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkclass">' + myarray[i] + '<span></span></label></td>';
                if ((i + 1) % 4 == 0) html += '</tr><tr>';
        }
        $("#tagstable tbody").append('<tr>' + html + '</tr>');
});
```

But when a user adds a new tag dynamically by clicking on **Add New Tag button**

I couldn't able to achive that functionality , could you please let me know how to display tags as per the above structure

In the below fiddle ,this can be reproduced 
if  clicked on **Add new tag button** more than 5 times

https://jsfiddle.net/dHZS9/717/

Could you please let me know how to resolve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jsfiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/dHZS9/718/)

```
 var counter = 0;
function appendToTagstable() {
    var taghtml = '';
    counter ++ ;
    taghtml = '<td><label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline"><input type="checkbox">I<span></span></label></td>';
     $("#tagstable tbody").append(taghtml);
    if(counter% 4 == 0) {
        $("#tagstable tbody").append("</tr><tr>");
    }

    return false;
 }
```

Use counter for it. It will help to maintain your structure.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to check if your last `tr` already has 4 `td` in it, If yes then create a new `tr` and append the `td` else just append the `td` to existing last `tr`.

Here is a **[working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dHZS9/719/)**

Below is the changes that was done to your code.

```
function appendToTagstable()
{  
    if($('#tagstable tbody tr:last').find('td').length > 3){ //check if tr already has 4 td's
      $('#tagstable tbody').append('<tr></tr>'); // add new tr as the old one already has 4 td's in it
    }   

    var taghtml = '';
    taghtml = '<td><label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline"><input type="checkbox">I<span></span></label></td>';
    $('#tagstable tbody tr:last').append(taghtml); //append td to last tr
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41356246/how-to-add-css-transform-to-the-current-transform-value-using-jquery

Answer (score 1):

A simple fix to this would be to count how many `td` elements are in the final `tr` before the append. If there are already `4` added, create a new `tr` and append to that. Try this:

```js
var myarray = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"]

$(document).ready(function() {
    var html = ''
    for (var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
        html += '<td><label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkclass">' + myarray[i] + '<span></span></label></td>';
        if (i + 1 % 4 == 0) 
            html += '</tr><tr>';
    }
    $("#tagstable tbody").append('<tr>' + html + '</tr>');
});

$(document).on("click", ".addTagbtn", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    appendToTagstable();
});

function appendToTagstable() {
    var $lastTr = $('#tagstable tr:last');
    if ($lastTr.find('td').length == 4)
     $lastTr = $('<tr />').appendTo('#tagstable');
        
    $lastTr.append('<td><label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline"><input type="checkbox">I<span></span></label></td>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="tagstable">
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success addTagbtn">Add new tag</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You already know what you need to do given you have this code -

```
if ((i + 1) % 4 == 0) html += '</tr><tr>';
```

You need to count how many is the current row when adding more tags and add a new row if you have met your limit

Answer (score 0):

You could add the following to the `appendToTagstable` function.

It simply counts the items in the last `tr` and then if there are 4, it will add another one.

```
var items = $("#tagstable tbody tr").last().children().length;
if(items === 4)
{
  $("#tagstable tbody").append('<tr></tr/>');
}
```

In addition the line in that function `$("#tagstable tbody").append(taghtml);` should be changed to `$("#tagstable tbody tr").last().append(taghtml);` which just ensures you are always adding a `td` to a `tr` element and not a tbody

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
var myarray = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]

$(document).ready(function(){
 function reload(){
  var html = ''
        for (var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++){
                html += '<td><label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-outline"><input type="checkbox" class="chkclass">' + myarray[i] + '<span></span></label></td>';
        if ((i + 1) % 4 == 0) html += '</tr><tr>';
        }
        $("#tagstable tbody").append('<tr>' + html + '</tr>');
 }
 reload();
  $(document).on("click", ".addTagbtn", function(event){
      var getData = prompt("Please enter your alphabet", "");
          if (getData != null) {
           myarray.push(getData);
            $("#tagstable tbody").html('');
           reload();
          }else
           return;
          
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="tagstable">
   <tbody>
    
   </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success addTagbtn">Add new alphabet</button>
```