# How to add css transform to the current transform value Using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Currently I have a class with transform value `rotate(57deg)`, when alert

`$(".div-1").css("transform")`  it is giving matrix value.

```
<style> 
 .div-1{
     transform: rotate(57deg);
     }                 
</style>   
<div class="div-1">Test</div>
```

> I need to add  `scale(-1, 1)`  to the existing  transform  value **using
>   Jquery**

. so .div-1 transform value become `div-1 {  transform: scale(-1, 1) rotate(57deg);  }` How to do this ?  Here 57 is just a number , it will change always. so what I need is add `scale( -1 , 1)` to the current transform value . Please help .

Comment: Create a class with the scale in it and then just dynamically add the class to the div: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35429935/how-do-i-animate-a-scale-css-property-using-jquery

Comment: `$(".div-1").css("transform","scale(-1,1) rotate("+yourDeg+"deg)");` is not working?

Comment: should `57` be a variable?

Comment: 57 is variable. consider it as a n degree.

Comment: Try the comment given by @AntalGyuri, it should work.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808096/using-css-transform-property-in-jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808096/using-css-transform-property-in-jquery)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do something like this :

```
var css = $('.div-1').css("transform");
css = css+" scale(-1,1)";
$('.div-1').css('transform',css);
```

Comment: Yes this is working . I never thought it is this much simple . When seeing matrix value , i didn't try any thing  & i just asked  without trying . Thank you friend .

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
    div {
        -ms-transform: rotate(57deg); // IE 9  
        -webkit-transform: rotate(57deg); // Chrome, Safari, Opera  
        transform: rotate(57deg);
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

ALternate solution is to create two classes as

```
<style> 
 .div-1{
     transform: rotate(57deg);
     }    
  .div-2{
     transform: scale(-1, 1) rotate(57deg);
     }             
</style>   
<div class="div-1">Test</div>
```

then in jquery do the following :

```
if(condition == true){
$(".div-1").addClass("div-1");
$(".div-1").removeClass("div-2");
} else {
$(".div-1").addClass("div-2");
$(".div-1").removeClass("div-1");
}
```

Comment: This is not correct answer friend .  Because here one time either i get scale effect or i get rotate effect . But i need both at a time as i explained .div-1 {  transform: scale(-1, 1) rotate(57deg);  }

Comment: once the class div-2 will be applies you will get both effect , what is the issue